# input file on change trigger form submit does not work

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JeremyHuang_Stern/zJcsZ/1/

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/imageUpload" class='imageForm'>
    <input type='file' name='image' id='testinput'>
</form>

$("#testinput").on("change",function(){
    alert("it changes !!")
    $(".imageForm").submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("it is submitted!!")
    })
});
```

I try to ajax submit the form once the user have selected an image. However, as can be seen in the fiddle, the second alert is not triggered.

What is the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: You are just listening to the `submit` event there, how the second `alert` should be called? `.submit()` the form you will see the `alert` s. http://jsfiddle.net/A9nxH/. Note that binding event handler within other event handlers is recipe for pain.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much. I have changed the code now it is working.